# Why is executing getChar in a terminal different to executing it in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Char

main = do 
    c <- getChar
    if not $ isUpper c
        then do putChar $ toUpper c
                main
        else putChar '\n'
```

Loading and executing in GHCi:

```
λ> :l foo.hs
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ> main
ñÑsSjJ44aAtTR
λ>
```

This consumes one character at time.

But in a terminal:

```
[~ %]> runhaskell foo.hs
utar,hkñm-Rjaer 
UTAR,HKÑM-
[~ %]>
```

it consumes one line at time.

Why does it behave differently?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you run a program in terminal it uses `LineBuffering` by default, but in `ghci` it is set to `NoBuffering`. You can read about it [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/ghci-faq.html). You will have to remove buffering from `stdin` and `stdout` to get the similar behavior.

```
import Data.Char
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    foo
foo = do
    c <- getChar
    if not $ isUpper c
        then do putChar $ toUpper c
                foo
        else putChar '\n'
```

Comment: Then `ghci` use `NoBuffering` by default, but the facto in every program is `LineBuffering`, yes?

Comment: Yes in terminal it is LineBuffering by default.

Comment: Is there a difference between disabling buffering and flushing, i.e. replacing `putChar x` with `do { putChar x; hflush stdout; }`?

Comment: yes, flush stdout is like sending the output from buffer to stdout.